# Mixing openni_kinect with cturtle possible?

Tags: ros, cturtle, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am a user of ROS. I install cturtle last. Now I find that openni_kinect needs later version ROS. How can I make it run in cturtle without installing a new version of ROS? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12690/mixing-openni_kinect-with-cturtle-possible?/) by [Eric Huo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1667/eric-huo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_kinect probably requires some functionality that is not in cturtle, so it may simply be impossible to get it to work.

You can always try to download it yourself and try to compile it with cturtle, then see where it fails, and attempt to fix/adjust the places where the compile fails, though it may take more experience with ROS than you have.

So, I'd just recommend upgrading to the latest, and you'll save yourself a lot of time and frustration.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-19**:
Indeed, it is extremely unlikely that openni_kinect could be made to work with cturtle.  You would essentially have to port the Electric version of most of the major vision libraries in ROS back to C Turtle, at which point you might as well use Electric.